# PHP $result = mysql_query($query) returns true even if there is no value in database

Tags: php

I have the following code.

```
$query = "SELECT HealthStatus FROM healthstatus where HealthStatus=$HealthStatus";

    $result = mysql_query($query);

    echo $HealthStatus;

    if($result = false)
            {
              //do something
            }

            else
            {
              //print value already exists
            }
```

I don't get any error or warning when the code is executed. But, even if $HealthStatus exists in database, the if part gets executed. When I give echo $HealthStatus, the value fetched is printed correctly.
I have tried using if(!$result). That doesn't work either. Can someone help me.

Comment: This is a problem: `if($result = false)`

Comment: I have tried using if(!$result). That gives the same output.

Comment: *even if `$HealthStatus` exists in database, the else part gets executed* - You're testing for `$result` being `false`; if it is *not* (*the value exists, query returns a result*), the `else` will be executed? Whatever you're trying to describe is what it sounds like you're getting. Also, you should be using `MYSQLI`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use mysql_num_rows to know if the query returned any rows, eg:-

```
if($result && mysql_num_rows($result))
{
  // a row exists
}
else
{
  // do something
}
```

also if HealthStatus is a string it needs to be enclosed in quotes eg:-

```
$query = "SELECT HealthStatus FROM healthstatus where HealthStatus='".$HealthStatus."'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if($result && mysql_num_rows($result))
{
  // a row exists
  $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
  echo "Health status was ".$row["HealthStatus"];
}
else
{
  // do something
  echo "There were no rows found";
}
```

Comment: Even after using if($result && mysql_num_rows($result)), I get the same output.

Comment: Is HealthStatus a string?  If so you need to wrap it in single quotes in the query eg HealthStatus='".$HealthStatus.'"

Comment: Yes HealthStatus is a string. I have tried wrapping it within quotes as well.

Comment: i've added some code above, let me know if it works and, if not, what it outputs

Comment: I tried the code above. Even if the HealthStatus already exists, it goes to the else part.

Comment: Are you calling mysql_connect and selecting the database correctly in the code before the snippet you posted?

Comment: yes. I have an include file in my code which connects to the database.

Answer (score 0):

To understand how much rows were received use `mysql_num_rows` function.

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

} else { 

}
```

Also, you have error in your `if`:

```
if($result = false)
        {
          //do something
        }

        else
        {
          //print value already exists
        }
```

You assign false to $result in your `if` statement.

You have to use `if($result == false)`.

To avoid such mistakes you can change order:

```
if(false == $result)
```

This will work, but this:

```
if(false = $result)
```

Will cause error.

Hope, this will help.

Comment: If I use if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0), I get this. Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource